# Php Json Associative Array To Java Map

Tags: java, php, json, gson

My problem is, PHP encodes arrays differently, based on if they are consecutive & begin with a zero index, or not. Example:

```
$arr = array(array(12), array(13));
===> [[12], [13]]

$arr = array("0" => array(12), "1" => array(13));
===> [[12], [13]]

$arr = array("0" => array(12), "2" => array(13));
===> {"0": [12], "2": [13]}
```

Why is the third one so radically different?

The first example produces a list of lists, the third example produces an object with lists. I need to convert all of these to Java 's `Map<Integer, List<Double>>`. That is the most generic datatype I could find in Java for these PHP objects. I am using Gson from Google. However, since the examples produces different types of objects, I cannot just read this into a map. I have to first check if it has indices and then adding one by one to a custom map. Please look at the line that says "THERE HAS TO BE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS PART". This is my code:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Saving {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "[[12], [13]]";
        json = json.trim();
        Map<Integer, List<Double>> fuelSavings = null;

        // such a cluster****
        if(json.startsWith("[[")) { // THERE HAS TO BE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS PART
        // ANY WAY I CAN AVOID THIS ENTIRE IF CONDITION

            //implicit keys
            fuelSavings = new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
            List<List<Double>> temporaryList = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<List<Double>>>(){}.getType());
            int index = 0;
            for(List<Double> temporaryListMember: temporaryList) {
                fuelSavings.put(index, temporaryListMember);
                index++;
            }

        } else {

            // explicit keys
            // THIS PART IS PERFECT
            fuelSavings = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<Integer, List<Double>>>(){}.getType());

        }

        System.out.println(fuelSavings);

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do in PHP are two different things. Array in PHP serves as Arrays, Maps, Lists.

`array(array(12), array(13));` and `array("0" => array(12), "2" => array(13));` are not the same even in PHP.

What you need to do in Java using Gson is to parse the json as String and check whether the main object is a `Map` or a `List` and then advise. If you have loaded a List then you know it was a `array(array(12), array(13));` otherwise it was the other one.

Can't you do something from the PHP side to generate it always the same?

**Edit:**

If you cannot do anything from the PHP side then your check will be identical to instantiate a `JsonParser` parse then checking if [`JsonObject.isJsonArray()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#isJsonArray%28%29) returns true, except that it will be eventually quicker but you won't rely on the gson library.

```
Map<Integer, List<Double>> fuelSavings = null;
JsonElement jElement = new JsonParser().parse("[[12], [13]]");
JsonObject jObject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
if (jObject.isJsonArray()) {
    fuelSavings = new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
    List<List<Double>> temporaryList = new Gson().fromJson(jElement, new TypeToken<List<List<Double>>>(){}.getType());
    int index = 0;
    for(List<Double> temporaryListMember: temporaryList) {
        fuelSavings.put(index++, temporaryListMember);
    }
} else /* this is a map */ {
    fuelSavings = new Gson().fromJson(jElement, new TypeToken<Map<Integer, List<Double>>>(){}.getType());
}
```

Comment: I know they are not the same (I was looking at the different json they produce, even though they have the same structure). `$arr = array("0" => array(12));` and `$arr = array(array(12));` are the same thing. The problem is, if they are not consecutive and do not begin with zero, it is no longer just a list of lists. PHP does not allow my go generate the same thing for any array, that's the sad part.

Comment: see my edit about `JSonParser` in order to check using the library instead of `String.startsWith`

Comment: I was looking to avoiding the whole if condition and not having to manually make the map from a list of lists. But this is an option. Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible because you have to deal with two different types, Map and List don't have a common interface, but you already know that. If you cannot make sure on the php side that all arrays are generated as Maps in Json, then you will have to do this check on the Java side.

Comment: @Unless you know PHP better than me, which I hope you do, we just use json_encode, which doesn't have a bitmask that enables to change the type is produces.

Comment: There seems to have `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` that will force output as Json Object (meaning Maps in Java), but I didn't see something telling it to do it only on first level, which will generate `{"0":{"0":12},"2":{"0":13}}`. This is not what you want either.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting!

As I understood, PHP server serves its data as an ordered map encoded as JSON, but some times in a bad luck its keys are consecutive integers, which makes `json_encode()` understand it as a simple array and use a different format for the outputted JSON.

As I understand, all PHP arrays are ordered maps. But when one array has consecutive integer keys, `json_encode()` generates an array with no keys intead a "JSON Object" (map). And that breaks client's code that's not expecting an array instead of an "object".

Incredibly, I found no existing Java function to convert a `JsonArray` to a `JsonObject`, and we may even face some Exception sometimes if we try to get an array as an Object! Gosh, a `JsonArray` is just a `JsonObject` with implicit consecutive integer keys, it should be casted automatically!! :p

I didn't try it, but maybe `JsonObject::entrySet()` can solve it. It returns a  `Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>>`, which maybe may be converted to a `Map<Integer, AnyObject>`, if Integer parses String automatically and `JsonElement` can be converted with a proper `TypeToken`.